# A Linq ContainsAll Method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items that can each have multiple keywords so I have three tables

```
Item -> ItemKeyword <- Keyword
```

I want to return all Items where the Item has all keywords in a list. so for example:

```
Item 1 has keywords "Rabbit", "Dog", "Cat" 
Item 2 has keywords "Rabbit", Hedgehog", "Dog"
```

I want to return only those items that have both "Dog" and "Cat" as keywords.

I cant use a contains query as that will essentially return all those items with "Dog" OR "Cat".

So I guess what I am asking for is if there is such a thing called ContainsAll in linq, or if there is some way I can perform this functionality.

I have attempted to use Except and Intersect but I cant seem to get the correct results.

I would like to have a single query so that it is easy to compile the query but this is not a dealbreaker.

I am using:

1. Dot Net 4.5
2. Visual Studio 2012
3. C#
4. Linq
5. Entity Framework
6. Sql Server Ce 4.0

Comment: Except is the way forward, I would say - so show us what you've got. I would expect `!largeCollection.Except(smallCollection).Any())` to check that everything in `smallCollection` is in `largeCollection`.

Comment: I would use `Intersect` - `if(largeCollection.Intersect(smallCollection).Count == smallCollection.Count)` should assert that all items from `smallCollection` are in `largeCollection` as well.

Comment: Either that or `largeCollection.Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains("Dog") && x.Keywords.Contains("Cat"))` which would avoid creating another collection and is a bit more readable, but Jon's is more succinct.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can it be that your example is wrong? Oo I think it needs to be `!smallCollection.Except(largeCollection).Any( )`

Comment: @Viper: Yes, that's what I meant. Oops. Good job I didn't put it in an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this .. code is written lengthier for better understanding .. Assuming each item as an identifier to check

```
        List<item> ItemsList = new List<item>();
        item item1 = new item();
        item1.ID = "1";
        item1.keywords = new List<string>();
        item1.keywords.Add("Rabbit");
        item1.keywords.Add("Dog");
        item1.keywords.Add("Cat");

        ItemsList.Add(item1);

        item item2 = new item();
        item2.ID = "2";
        item2.keywords = new List<string>();
        item2.keywords.Add("Rabbit");
        item2.keywords.Add("Hedgehog");
        item2.keywords.Add("Dog");

        ItemsList.Add(item2);

        //this the list you want to check
        var values = new List<string> (); 
        values.Add("Dog");
        values.Add("Cat");

        var result = from x in ItemsList
                     where !(values.Except(x.keywords).Any())
                     select x;

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
          // Check the item.ID;

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

> I cant use a contains query as that will essentially return all those items with "Dog" OR "Cat".

This is simply not true. You can use two contains with an `AND` && :

```
items.Where(item => item.Keywords.Contains("Dog") && item.Keywords.Contains("Cat"));
```

Or you can put the values you are looking for in an array then use `All` method to make it shorter:

```
var values = new [] { "Dog", "Cat" };
items.Where(item => values.All(item.Keywords.Contains));
```